# Only last trigger in sequence is doing its job C#

Tags: c#, triggers, method-chaining

My case is this:

```
    public Pocetna_forma()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Timer_reset(new TimeSpan(19, 09, 00));
        Timer_bolovanje(new TimeSpan(19, 09, 10));
        Timer_godisnji(new TimeSpan(19, 09, 20));          
        Timer_godisnji_insert(new TimeSpan(19, 09, 30));
        Timer_bolovanje_insert(new TimeSpan(19, 09, 40));
    }
```

So I placed starting condition of my triggers in my main form constructor, and every trigger is the same except the method that it runs (basically they are all the same but with different querys). This is how my trigger+method looks like:

```
    private void Timer_reset(TimeSpan alertTime)
    {
        DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;
        if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            return;//time already passed
        }
        this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
        {
            this.Trigger_brisanje();
        }, null, timeToGo, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    }

    private void Trigger_brisanje()
    {
        NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(Connectionstring);
        conn.Open();

        NpgsqlCommand upis_odlaska = new NpgsqlCommand("begin;update zaposlenici set polje_stanje=1,vrijeme3=null,vrijeme2=null;commit;", conn);
        upis_odlaska.ExecuteReader();

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Then I tried to move calling trigger methods one behind another and found out that if I place for ex. "Timer_godisnji_insert" after "Timer_bolovanje_insert", only "Timer_godisnji_insert" will kick off. Im new with triggers so I don't know where the bug is, anyone?

Comment: Are you using the `timer` member in each method? If so, you need to use a separate named timer member for each method. So, `timer_reset` for `Timer_reset`, `timer_bolovanje` for `Timer_bolovanje`, etc... What you're currently doing is resetting the `timer` field in each function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning every timer to the same field. Either use one field for each timer or put all timers in a list and use lock to keep the list synced when adding or removing timers.

Comment: Fixed it, that was a dumb question, idk how I missed that...thanks for seeing that

Comment: Been there, done that. At some point you'll see that stuff at a glance in a huge pile of code someone else wrote.